# short int to unsigned int conversion network byte order C++

Tags: c++, networking, byte, unsigned, short

I have a two-byte short int pointer array `short int* hostdata` and want to convert it to a 4-byte unsigned int with network byte order `unsigned int* net_data`. Is it okay if I write it like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numsamples; ++i)
  net_data[i] = htonl((unsigned int)hostdata[i]);
```

or should I do it with reinterpret_cast like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numsamples; ++i)
  net_data[i] = htonl(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(reinterpret_cast<short int*>hostdata[i]));
```

Comment: Your 2 code examples don't seem to be equivalent to me as you cast to pointers in your seconds example without dereferencing - intended? Also, which kind of conversion do you want to achieve? short int can have negative numbers, unsigned int can not - would you prefer an underflow in that case? truncation? reinterpretation?

Comment: What do you want to do with negative values?

Comment: Do you have an array of pointers, `short int *hostdata[SIZE]`, or an array of numbers `short int hostdata[SIZE]`? If the latter, what do you want to do with negative numbers?

Comment: @Joni according to his edit he has none - just a pointer to short int (pointers and arrays are __not__ the same)

Comment: @griffin "short int pointer array" still sounds a lot like an array of pointers to `short int`. And the second sample still interprets the array values as pointers.

Comment: @Joni haha you're right. He has a "short int pointer array" which is just a pointer to a short int. Contradicting himself ;)

Comment: initially I have a char* mbufr;  mbufr = new char[bufLength]; then hostdata = (short*) mbufr; and afterwards, I want to put hostdata into unsigned int * in network byte order.

Comment: So each of the `short` values should become one `unsigned int` value, or should two be combined into one? What about negative values?

Comment: :). Well that it right. I was thinking the data is always positive but not. So it will be normal int. And I want to combine two into one. Thats right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `short integers`, then why use `htonl` when you can use `htons`.

- htonl stands for host to network long
- htons stands for host to network short

Remember, almost all combinations of h,n,l,s exist, except for the stupid ones like `stonhl`

Don't overcomplicate things, add them into a struct and send them as such.

```
struct MsgHead
{
    unsigned short utype;
    unsigned short usize;
};

// 8 bytes, no padding will be added by the compiler
struct MyPacket
{
    // Header (optional)
    MsgHead        head; // 4 bytes
    unsigned short myData[2]; // 4 bytes
};
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to store 2 byte format data (short int) into 4 byte format (int). Should not I use htonl for that?

Comment: @AvbAvb Use a `struct` to hold both `short`s and `htons` to convert them to network order.